# Should toggling icon indicate current status or new status?

Tags: icons, consistency

I'm working on a data-mgmnt app and came across this deeply philosophical question: I have an icon to represent if a record is locked or not. And if the record is not locked, it can be locked by clicking on that icon. In the same way, if the current user is the locking user, he can unlock the record by clicking that icon.

Now the question is: should the icon for unlocked records be an icon of an open lock or a closed lock? In other words: should it represent the current status or the action it will trigger???